# Pop from empty list errors

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I'm writing a code to pop from a list consisting of 3 nested list. 
I want to pop the last element starting from the end of the first inner loop. it works fine until it reaches the first element and return (IndexError: pop from empty list). How to handle this condition using the range function?

```
toappendlst= [[[62309, 1, 2], [62309, 4, 2], [6222319, 4, 2], [6235850, 4, 2], [82396378, 4, 3], [94453486, 4, 3], [0, 0, 0]],[[16877135, 6, 2], [37247278, 7, 2],    [47671207, 7, 2], [0, 0, 0]]]

for chro in range(-1,len(toappendlst)):
            popdPstn = toappendlst[chro].pop()
            print(popdPstn)
```

O\P

```
[0, 0, 0]
[47671207, 7, 2]
[37247278, 7, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python33\trial.py", line 41, in <module>
 popdPstn = toappendlst[chro].pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Use `range(len(toappendlst))`. More preferably simply iterate the list: `for lst in toappendlst: popdPstn = lst.pop() ...`

Comment: Cannot replicate. The code you have posted prints different things, and does not throw the error.

Comment: I kind of think that this question should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: pop from empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216428/python-pop-from-empty-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating in `range(-1, len(lst))`, which is a range of `len(lst)+1` numbers (-1 to `len(lst)-1` inclusive). This is more than the number of elements in the list, and so your final `.pop` operates on an empty list.

You may not need to actually pop from the list. For example, `for item in reversed(lst):` will iterate over the list in reverse order (same order as you would be popping off the list), without destroying the list contents.

Alternately, if you really need to pop every item off of the list, then just iterate `for i in xrange(len(lst))` to iterate `len(lst)` times. If you need the indices in reverse order, `for i in reversed(xrange(len(lst)))`.

Comment: Thank you @nneonneo .. I've fixed the first case. I don't have to start from (-1).  I need to pop since toappendlst is the input list and I'm gonna insert the popped value to an outerlst ..  What I've done to handle the case is adding a while loop . 
    outerlst = []
    for chrom in range(len(toappendlst)):
                outerlst.append([])
                 while (len(toappendlst[chrom]) > 0 ):
                popdPstn = toappendlst[chrom].pop()

Answer (score 0):

change your list with....

```
toappendlst= [[[62309, 1, 2]], [[62309, 4, 2]], [[6222319, 4, 2]], [[6235850, 4, 2]], [[82396378, 4, 3]], [[94453486, 4, 3]], [[0, 0, 0]],[[16877135, 6, 2]], [[37247278, 7, 2]],    [[47671207, 7, 2]], [[0, 0, 0]]]
```

or you can use a sequence for list like...

```
toappendlst= [[62309, 1, 2], [62309, 4, 2], [6222319, 4, 2], [6235850, 4, 2], [82396378, 4, 3], [94453486, 4, 3], [0, 0, 0],[16877135, 6, 2], [37247278, 7, 2],    [47671207, 7, 2], [0, 0, 0]]
for chro in toappendlst[::-1]:
        print(chro)
```

Comment: I don't have to play with the list since this is only a test list but I'm gonna input from a txt file.

Comment: ok then **toappendlst[::-1]** is working for your list.

Comment: It does work. Thank you @ajay. This is new to me . can u give a brief explanation about what does this structure stand for?

Comment: yes,its call a slicing in python. syntax: **list[start_position:end_position:(optional)step]**
step have numeric value like 1,2,... and negative value iterate list in reverse order.

Comment: I was aware about the start and end thing. I thought number of steps is working only with range function. Thank you @ajay