# Python: pop from empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using below line in a loop in my code

```
importer = exporterslist.pop(0)
```

If `exporterslist` has no entries it returns `error: IndexError: pop from empty list`. How can I bypass exporterslist with no entries in it?

One idea I can think of is if exporterslist is not None then `importer = exporterslist.pop(0)`
else get the next entry in the loop.
If the idea is correct, how to code it in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the next entry in the loop"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
if exporterslist: #if empty_list will evaluate as false.
    importer = exporterslist.pop(0)
else:
    #Get next entry? Do something else?
```

Comment: is it must to use 'else' after 'if'?

Comment: nope! You don't need the `else` clause, you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 15):

This one..

**`exporterslist.pop(0) if exporterslist else False`**

..is somewhat the same as the accepted answer of @nightshadequeen's just shorter:

```
>>> exporterslist = []   
>>> exporterslist.pop(0) if exporterslist else False   
False
```

or maybe you could use this to get no return at all:

**`exporterslist.pop(0) if exporterslist else None`**

```
>>> exporterslist = [] 
>>> exporterslist.pop(0) if exporterslist else None
>>>
```

Comment: This is for the ones who _need_ to have a one-liner: personally I'd rather have the if statement, because it's easier to read and understand. If you don't need to easily read and understand then go for it.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use a try/except

```
try:
    importer = exporterslist.pop(0)
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
```

If you are always popping from the front you may find a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) a better option as deque.popleft() is  `0(1)`.

Comment: Upvoting as this keep the thread-safe property of pop, and is EAFP

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
if exporterslist:
    importer = exporterslist.pop(0)
```

Comment: `if exporterslist:` will do the same job

Comment: @pedjjj Thank you for your suggestion. Have included it.

Answer (score -3):

You can also .pop() only if the list has items in it by determining if the length of the list is 1 or more:

```
if len(exporterslist) >= 1: #if the length of the list is equal or higher than one
    importer = exporterslist.pop()
```

Comment: `if len(exporterslist) > 0`