# Index error: pop from empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm fairly new at coding python... Trying to understand the .pop() function and how to pop an item from a list and append to a new list. Can someone help me with this code to see why it's telling me that I'm popping from an empty list?

```
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"] 
new_list = []

while len(new_list) <= 8:
    stuff = more_stuff.pop() 
    print "Adding: ", stuff
    new_list.append(stuff)

print new_list
```

I'm getting this result when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpop.py", line 5, in <module>
    stuff = more_stuff.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: pop from empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216428/python-pop-from-empty-list)

Answer (score 3):

The indexes in a list starts from zero.

So, in `more_stuff[7]` you will get *'Boy'* which is the last one.

Your code is trying to pop another element after *'Boy'* which does not exist.

All you need to fix is:

```
while len(new_list) <= 7:
```

**EDIT:**

You could do it with list comprehension as well:

```
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana",
"Girl", "Boy"] 

new_list = [more_stuff.pop() for __ in xrange(len(more_stuff))]

print new_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and help, all of you

Answer (score 0):

while `more_stuff` is empty, `len(more_stuff)=0` , the `pop()` will still work .

Use `list` as condition, if the list is empty, the bool value is `False`

```
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana",
"Girl", "Boy"] 
new_list = []
while more_stuff:
    stuff = more_stuff.pop() 
    print ("Adding: ", stuff)
    new_list.append(stuff)
```

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **bool**()    or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or    bool value False.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your condition on the `more_stuff` list, because that will run out of items:

```
while len(more_stuff) > 0:
    ...
```

Comment: Should be just `while more_stuff:`