# Hackerrank shows IndexError: pop from empty list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using the `pop` function for eliminating one value from list. In pyCharm my code runs well. But when I try to run this on Hackerrank it shows me `IndexError: pop from empty list`

I tried this:

```py
list = [] //this is the list which I declare.

    elif e == 'pop': //this is the else if condition which is needed.
        list.pop()
```

Here is my code

```py
n = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    e = input()
    if e == 'insert':
        j = int(input())
        k = int(input())
        list.insert(j,k)
    elif e == 'print':
        print(list)
    elif e == 'remove':
        j = int(input())
        list.remove(j)
    elif e == 'append':
        j = int(input())
        list.append(j)
    elif e == 'sort':
        list.sort()
    elif e == 'pop':
        list.pop()
    elif e == 'reverse':
        list.reverse()
```

I expect the output

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: pop from empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216428/python-pop-from-empty-list)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to check the list is empty or not before `pop` .If list is empty,there are no elements can  `pop` .You can use `len` to check it.

Comment: Okay I got my answer

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try `pop()` on an empty `list` 
It works on your local machine and does not run on **Hackerrank**, because of their test cases.
 They have hidden test-cases, where they're testing the `pop()` functionality on an empty list.

Add a simple validation in your code while popping an element from the list.

```
if e == 'pop':
  if list:
    list.pop()
```

The `if list:` basically checks whether the list is empty or not.
If the list is empty, then it returns `False` and vice-versa.